# Prove matrix $A$ is invertible if the set is linearly independent

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and $\{v_1, ... , v_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $\{Av_1, ... , Av_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff $A$ is invertible.

**Forward direction:** Assume $\{Av_1, ... , Av_n\}$ is a basis, we show $A$ is invertible.

So we know that $\{Av_1, ... , Av_n\}$ is linearly indepedent.

$\implies c_1Av_1 + \dotsb   + c_nAv_n = 0$ with $c_1 = \dotsb= c_n = 0$

$\implies A(c_1v_1 + \dotsb+ c_nv_n) = 0$

Let $x = c_1v_1 + \dotsb +c_nv_n$, then $x = 0$, so it follows that $\text{null } A = 0$, so it must be that $A$ is invertible.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, since $\text{null}\ A+\text{rank}\ A = n$ and $n = \text{rank}\ A$ iff $A$ is invertible, although this is a more general result.

Comment: I don't understand how you prove that null $A=0$ since you *suppose* $c_1=\dots=c_n=0$. You're not taking  *any* $x\in$ null $A$ and *deduce* $x=0$.